# Why are strings iterables in ES2015?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterable

Can someone please help me better understand the design decision of making JavaScript strings iterable in ES2015? Most iterables represent collections of other things: `Array`, `Set`, `Map`, `Generator` (kinda sorta). A string can only be a collection of strings (well, Unicode codepoints). Thus if you want a function to either accept a collection of strings (e.g. `Set` of strings or a generator that yields strings) *or* a single string, there’s no way to differentiate the user’s intent. Did she mean a single string or an iterable of codepoints? Iterating over characters seems like a corner case compared to passing around collections of strings. My inclination in this case would be to special-case string parameters when the (intended) type is `string` ∪ `Iterable<string>`.

```
function deleteDocuments(ids /* string or Iterable<string> */) {
  if('string' === typeof ids) { 
    deleteSingleDocById(ids);
  } else {
    for(let id of ids) { 
      deleteSingleDocById(id);
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If your function expects a single parameter, it'll either be an iterable string or an iterable array. Why not just make it process an iterable? Your dilemma is unclear.

Comment: FWIW this is also the way string iteration has worked in Python.

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: Seems to be a better question for https://esdiscuss.org/ .

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that’s exactly my point. If your input type is iterable there's no way to tell the difference between a string and an iterable of strings, since strings themselves are iterable.

Comment: @MiguelMota The function that accepts only an iterable still won't be able to tell the difference between a string (which is iterable) and an iterable of strings. I’ve changed the example above to be slightly less contrived.

Comment: @JustinMakeig What is `ids` ?  What do you mean by an "iterable of strings"? An array? What is purpose of `if..else` ? Not certain what expected result of `deleteDocuments` is? Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate issue?

Comment: @guest271314 the `deleteDocuments()` function takes a single string or a collection of strings and for each value, calls `deleteSingleDocById()` with a single id. I don't want to restrict myself to just accepting arrays, though. I'd like the caller to be able to specify any iterable, like a `Set` or a generator. This is obviously an over-simplified distillation.

Comment: Well so what? If you expect an iterable, do what you do to the iterable. If you're expecting a special kind of iterable, well maybe that design issue is the core problem.

Comment: @Pointy I’m hypothesizing that there’s a better way of doing the classic `[].concat(ids)` to coerce an array where it’s desirable to be able to pass a single value or an array of values. That technique only works for arrays, not iterables, like a generator, for example.

Comment: There's always `Array.isArray()` to do a robust "is this an array?" test.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, but I'm trying to generalize beyond arrays to iterables, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is really the continuation of a principle that preceded ES2015/ES6. Since the release of Internet Explorer 8, every browser has allowed you to loop over the contents of Arrays and Strings using the same syntax.

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

```
var string = 'abc';

for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  console.log(string[i]);
}
```

Strings were already "array-like"; they fulfilled the implicit array iteration protocol (of having `.length` and indexed properties), and each character was already treated as its own string when looked up. We could argue over whether that was the right choice, but it's distant history at this point. It would have been a weird divergence of behaviour if, post-ES2015, you were expected to use different syntaxes for iterating over Arrays and Strings.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. That’s what I figured. Seems like an unfortunate vestige to bring forward. If I want to iterate over the (array of) characters that make up my string, I'd actually prefer to be explicit with `'string'.split('')`. I guess that's neither here nor there, though, at this point.

Comment: I got burned by this today with `Promise.any(myValues)` ... Sadly I didn't realise a library 'could' sometimes return a string.. So I end up with 'h' as the result of the promise.. It was VERY confusing.